# which QT C++ or Java is good For Learning?

Tags: java, c++, qt

QT C++ programming is best for learning or java SE is best?
Which one?
Please help me

Comment: The two things you mention are completely different. If you want to learn Java, go with Java. If you want to learn C++ with Qt, go with Qt. The best probably: _learn both!_

Comment: This question will most likely be closed, as the answer depends on opinion, not on facts, I'm sure you can find an appropriate forum for your question elsewhere.Stack Overflow is for questions that require specific answers based on facts.Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Your Question is unclear.

Answer (score 5):

It comes down to your `needs`. What is most suitable for you. Both are great and fun to learn. I myself learned C++ first and then went to Java. I really enjoy working in both but I enjoy GUI work more in Java.

Again it comes to your skills and needs. If you are good with C++ and plan to stick with it in future than sure go with Qt C++ otherwise every language is good to learn as `every thing has its Pro's and Con's`..